# Augmented Reality plugins in Flutter

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality

Is it possible with any of the AR plugins that are currently in Flutter, to build something similar to this kind of app:

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/lightghost/id1274620384

If yes, what would be a good example to get started?

If not, what would be another good approach regarding this?

I don't know the real capabilities of Flutter in Augmented Reality area.